# What should the [bloodline] tag be used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [bloodline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bloodline) currently has no excerpt. This tag is currently used mostly to talk about the Bloodline Arcana in Pathfinder, but it is used in at least [one other question about Vampire the Dark Ages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88988/what-are-the-details-on-the-bonsam).

How should this tag be used and should it be specifically for Bloodline Arcana?

Comment: Splitting it up into different topics (sorcerer-bloodline, etc) is among our options.

Answer (score 4):

[bloodline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bloodline) is a bad tag in itself, as it can be too variable, thus it should be fixed, getting good excerpts that fit what they should be used for.

- Pathfinder & D&D sorcerers have bloodlines that are flavors of magic akin to magic schools.
- Vampire the Masquerade has bloodlines that are pretty much "sub-clans".
- Ninja RPG has bloodlines, that are clans/schools.
- Vampire the Requiem has Bloodlines, that are equally clan-like but different from Masquerade clans.

Comment: By "fixed", do you mean it should be split into tags appropriate to the various RPGs whose questions it's tagged on?

Comment: Of some sort. Like masquerade-bloodlines requiem-bloodlines sorcerer-bloodlines and ninja-rpg-bloodlines should they ever come up